# Why is effect of charge redistribution not considered while calculating electrostatic forces between two charged bodies

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Why is charge redistribution due to polarization/induction (depending on the medium), is not considered generally while calculating electrostatic force between two objects? (In this scenario, you can take two charged spheres of same size)

Conductors have their charge concentrated at their centres, so that's why Coulomb's law is used, but shouldn't still there be charge redistribution happening?

Is it because the effect of charge redistribution on force is very negligible that it is ignored?

Comment: Because textbook problems are generally oversimplified.

Answer (score 0):

There will indeed be some charge distribution when we consider two charged conductors and it will definitely affect the electrostatic force between the objects if they are close to each other.

if both the objects have the like charges then the 'effective distance' between the centers of the charges of the two bodies increases(due to repulsion) and the electrostatic force between them would be lesser than the force between them if you ignored the redistribution of charge

similarly if both the bodies have unlike charges, the electrostatic force between them would be greater than the force between them if you ignored the redistribution of charge.

But if the separation between the objects is very large,then the effect of induction can be neglected.